# Regular Expression for Ignoring specific digits

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to select all directories in a directory where these

```
1. start with any alpha
2. Not followed by a specific set of digits
3. Followed by a alpha numeric characters till the end
```

I tried following expression, but this is not working

```
^skk\/[a-zA-Z]*[^1][a-z0-9A-Z]*$"
```

however

```
 ^skk\/[a-zA-Z]*[^1]*$
```

works perfectly but doesn't solve my problem.

Here skk is root directory.

Example data
skk/abc123 should not be selected
skk/abc321 should be selected

Comment: What about `skk/abcdef`? Should it pass or not? It starts with alpha, it doesn't have `1` and ends with alphanumeric.

Comment: @jerry it should be selected as this does not contain 1. May be I can rephrase my question to all string where first digit in a string isn't  1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me that you're looking for a regex more like:

```
^skk\/(?![a-zA-Z]+1)[a-zA-Z]+[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/pE5oW9)

This ensures that the first digit after the alpha characters is not 1.

This assumes that the regex engine you use supports negative lookaheads.

The demo site explains the regex, but if you want me to elaborate, let me know.

Comment: yeah, that's it -- took me too long ;)

Comment: @Jerry, thank for quick help, my regex engine doesn't support negative lookaheads. But I believe I shall be able to take it further.

Answer (score 0):

Add an asterisk (*) or plus (+) after the last set [] and before the $.

- Asterisk means repeat previous pattern zero to infinite times. (matches skk/abc1 and skk/abc12)
- Plus means repeat previous pattern one to infinite times. (matches skk/abc12, fails to match skk/abc1)

Comment: i believe the OP needs to _change_ the asterisk to a plus

Comment: You are probably right.  I read and responded to the pre-edited version of the question where it wasn't clear that there was an asterisk after the last set.

Comment: @Slartibartfast, my apologies, didn't realize asterisk has different meaning.